# Passing object as a parameter in a constructor in PHP

Tags: php, oop, instantiation

I have the following two lines of code:

```
$speed = new Speed(1.5);
$car = new Car('Ford', 'Mondeo', $speed);
```

I don't get that passing of $speed part. There is a broader context but it is not needed to explain what I need
what can I research further, is this a dependency injection, or polymorphism?
I was looking at "php programming object as parameter in constructor" but I cant get a good info from the search results.

Comment: Well its nothing to do with Polymorphism, its just passing a parameter which is recently also called injection

Comment: So I can read up about dependency injection, as related to this? I had this coming up in the search results - https://blog.devgenius.io/php-p63-objects-as-arguments-dependency-injection-and-polymorphism-intro-2155d0391d04

Comment: There's nothing particularly special about passing an object as a parameter. It's just like any other value.

Comment: @Barmar - When I do that I get access to it's methods and properties in the object that I am passing it to, or some other things?

Comment: Dependency Injection refers to passing the object rather than the `Car` constructor calling `Speed()` itself. This allows the caller to use other classes that implement the same interface, rather than making `Car` specifically dependent on the `Speed` class.

Comment: `- When I do that I get access to it's methods and properties in the object that I am passing it to`...yes, in the Car constructor you can write (for example)  `$speed->whatever` to access the properties of that object. You could also save the variable to a private variable inside the Car class, so you can access it from other functions of the Car class...just like any other variable. In that respect, there is no difference really between scalar variables and objects or arrays...they are all just things you can pass around as variables between classes and functions.

Comment: I think what's being touched on here are aspects of SOLID design principles, namely [D]ependency Inversion. There are several variations on naming and specific implementation, but the gist of it is "pass dependencies into the object, rather than instantiating them inside the object". When taken together with other aspects of SOLID, like the [L]iskov Substitution Principle, you will find that your code is much easier to work with and maintain. I've found that [this article](https://accesto.com/blog/solid-php-solid-principles-in-php/) is a good summary of SOLID framed in the language of PHP.

Comment: The term "dependency injection" comes from design perspective but it isn't just synonym for non-scalar parameter. You can pass a `DateTime` object and nobody will call that dependency injection.